# APE ajax push engine tcp socket (jabber web client)

Tags: web, xmpp, chat, ape

I'm trying to make a web based chat using APE to create a TCP socket. Everything is working fine, but when I try to send many messages the socket breaks and I get the raw BAD_CHL.

```
var aux='<message from="'+user+'" to="'+rec+'"  xml:lang="en" type="chat">'           aux+=mensaje;
aux+='</message>';               
chat.get_socket().send(aux);
```

That is an example of my code to send a message. Has anyone had the same problem with APE and its tcpsockets?